# Help in this Inequality in Complex Numbers

Tags: inequality

Please help with this problem in Complex Numbers :(

Let z a Complex Number $\ne$ 0 such that |z³+ $\frac {1}{z^3}$| $\le$ 2. Prove that |z+ $\frac 1z$| $\le$ 2.

For solving this problem I tried

z³+ $\frac {1}{z^3}$ = (z+ $\frac 1z$) (z² -1 +$\frac {1}{z^2}$) and their modulus are equal

|z³+ $\frac {1}{z^3}$| = |(z+ $\frac 1z$) (z² -1 +$\frac {1}{z^2}$)|  , so

|(z+ $\frac 1z$) (z² -1 +$\frac {1}{z^2}$)| $\le$ 2

And the modulus of a product is the product of his modulus,

|(z+ $\frac 1z$)| |(z² -1 +$\frac {1}{z^2}$)| $\le$ 2

|(z+ $\frac 1z$)| $\le$ $\frac {2}{|(z² -1 +\frac {1}{z^2})|}$

Then i think i have to prove |(z² -1 +$\frac {1}{z^2}$)| $\ge$ 1

Is something wrong what i did?

Can you help me to continue or give some other way to do it.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider $|z+\frac{1}{z}|^3$

Solution: 
\begin{align}
|z+\frac{1}{z}|^3 &= |z^3 + 3z +3\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^3}| &&\text{using binomial theorem}
\\&\le|z^3 + \frac{1}{z^3}|+3|z+\frac{1}{z}| &&\text{by triangle inequality}
\\&\le 2 + 3|z+\frac{1}{z}| &&\text{by the hypothesis}
\end{align}

Now after the substitution $x := |z+\frac{1}{z}|$ one is left with
\begin{align}
&&x^3-3x-2 &\le 0\\
\implies&& (x-2)(x+1)^2 &\le 0 \\
\implies&& x&\le2 
\end{align}

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific :(

Comment: I posted a full solution